# How can I have attachment open up in a new window

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have enabled attachment in my custom webpart like below.

```
<xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
      <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ListId">
             {} </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
          <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
```

How can I add target="blank"?

Answer (score 4):

I've used jQuery in the past to find the link and add the attribute

$("a.yourclass").attr("target","_blank");

make sure to narrow it down to your items, otherwise all links will open in new windows

HTH

Comment: hm... nice tips.Tha
bUT It seems i would have to add an id to itself.
How did you get to your selector?

Comment: simplest way is to wrap you items with a div tag, and give that an ID, like $("#myDiv a").attr, or give each of your hyperlinks a unique class, and that can be used like $("a.yourClass").attr

Comment: David how do i add the class though:
An element  css class or ID doesn't exist by default.
How did you go with yours.Please elaborate.
This is my output below.
<tr id="{0052E8DD-52C3-4C5B-9052-9C4D69210C0E}">
<td class="ms-vb">
<span dir="ltr">
<a href="/sites/Intranet/Comm/Lists/Co/Attachments/1/indicator.gif" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', '', '1', '');return false;" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, '1', null, '');return false;" tabindex="1">indicator.gif</a>
</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>

Comment: I have actually managed to add the target="blank" but when i click it it doesn't open in a new window

Comment: Does it open in a new tab? And it should be target="_blank"

Comment: No it doesn't open in a new tab.
If it does i would be smiling :).
Cheers

Comment: This is the html output. <a href="/sites/Logo.jpg" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '0', '');return false;" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, '0', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '');return false;" tabindex="1" target="_blank">Logo.jpg</a> As you can see i tried adding target="blank" but still opens on the same window. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I removed the onclick and then added target=_blank and it WORKED

Answer (score 0):

Use the following js function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($("a[onclick*='DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect']"), function(i, anchor) {
       var attUrl =  $(this).attr("href");
       $(this).removeAttr("onclick");
       $(this).removeAttr("onmousedown");
       $(this).click(function (){ window.open(attUrl); return false;});
    });
});
```